# Undefined step error even though step is defined

Tags: python-behave

**I have the following BDD given statement in landing.py file**

use_step_matcher("re")

@given(u'that I land on the (page_name) landing page with the correct offer id (?:start network traffic)')

**My feature file is as follows:**

Scenario : DR lil page end2end test starting with utm parameters

```
Given that I land on the "google page" landing page with the correct offer id start network traffic
```

**When I try to run it says undefined step**

I am using the step matcher "re" and the text "start network traffic" in my given statement is optional. Why is it failing

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@given(u'that I land on the {page_name} landing page with the correct offer id (?:start network traffic)')
```